# Getting character from the Unicode code-point - C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I have got two questions.

1 - I get Unicode code-points and how do I get the character associated with this code-point? Something like:

```
int code_point = 0xD24;
char* chr = (char*) code_point;
```

But the above code fails by throwing exception.

2 - Suppose the code-point is stored in a file and I read the code-point to a string, how do I convert that to valid Unicode string?

I am looking for a platform independent solution. Any help would be great!

Comment: What encoding do you want the character in?

Comment: Any valid Unicode encoding. UTF-8 probably.

Comment: UTF-8 probably?  You need to know.  The code_points and even the lengths you need to look at will be different depending on the encoding.  See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) project? As per the site,

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of
>   C/C++ and Java libraries providing
>   Unicode and Globalization support for
>   software applications. ICU is widely
>   portable and gives applications the
>   same results on all platforms and
>   between C/C++ and Java software.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean to be assigning that value to a char (or more precisely, to a wchar_t), not a char* ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the *name* of the character? [u_charName()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a488f2a373998c7decb0ecd3e3552079) in ICU will do this, returning something like `LATIN SMALL LETTER A`.